# Showing convergence of an infinite ODE system

Tags: ca.classical-analysis-and-odes, ds.dynamical-systems, asymptotics

Suppose $\{a_n(t)\}_{n \geq 0}$ is a collection of differentiable (or simply smooth) functions such that i) $0 \leq a_n(0) \leq 1$ for all $n\in \mathbb N$ (ii) $a_n(t) \approx 1 - \mu2^{-n}$ uniformly in $t$ for $n \gg 1$ (iii) $a'_n = a^2_{n+1} - a_n.$ My goal is to show that $$a_n(t) \xrightarrow{t \to \infty} \mathrm{e}^{-\mu 2^{-n}} \quad \text{for all $n \in \mathbb N$.}$$ Any help (or hints) will be greatly appreciated!

---

Remark: The condition (ii) is a bit unclear, I should emphasize here that $a_n(t) < 1$ for all (fixed) $n \in \mathbb N$ and for all $t \geq 0$, this is the reason that I did not write condition (ii) as
condition (ii') $a_n(t) \approx 1$ uniformly in $t$ for $n \gg 1$.

---

Remark: As discussed in the comments, I need to impose an initial datum ${a_n(0)}_{n \geq 0}$ such that $\sup_{n \in \mathbb N} a_n(0) = 1$ but there does not exists an $N \in \mathbb N$ for which $a_N(0) = 1$. Also, one can savely assume that $a_n(0) < a^2_{n+1}(0)$ for all $n \in \mathbb N$.

Comment: Can you be more precise about your condition (ii)?

Comment: @AnthonyQuas Hello, condition (ii) enforces that for every $t \geq 0$, $|a_n(t) - (1-\mu2^{-n})|$ converges to $0$ when $n \to \infty$.

Comment: Hello Fei. This doesn't sound like uniform convergence to me (which is what you wrote in the original question). Also, why is your condition different from "for every $t\ge 0$, $a_n(t)\to 1$ as $n\to\infty$"?

Comment: @FeiCao: something is a bit odd: the point $(e^{-\mu 2^{-1}}, e^{-\mu 2^{-2}},e^{-\mu 2^{-3}},...) \in \left[0,1\right]^{\infty}$ is not equilibrium of the system and thus, it cannot be the attractor of this dynamical system -- or am I missing something? The only equilibria that I could spot were the origin and $(1,1,1,...)$. It feels like the origin is the global attractor...

Comment: @AugustoSantos Hello, you can check that the ansatz $a_n = \mathrm{e}^{-\mu 2^{-n}}$ indeed satisfies $a^2_{n+1} = a_n$ for all $n$

Comment: @AnthonyQuas Dear Professor, please see my edited question for further clarification.

Comment: Hello Fei, so this question is interesting to me, but I still don’t know exactly what you’re asking. One possible question would be: suppose $a_n(0)\in (0,1)$ for each $n$. Is it true that there exists a $\mu$ such that $a_n(t)\to \exp(-2^{-n}\mu)$.

Comment: Dear Professor, the condition that $a_n(t) \to 1 - \mu 2^{-n}$ as $ t \to \infty$ for all large enough $n$ is an assumption which can be of some help...

Comment: Hello Fei, I think if $a_n(t)\to 1-\mu 2^{-n}$ then $a_{n-1}(t)\to (1-\mu 2^{-n})^2\ne 1-\mu 2^{-(n-1)}$ so that your assumption cannot be satisfied. On the other hand, if $a_n(t)\to \exp(-\mu 2^{-n})$ then $a_{n-1}(t)\to \exp(-\mu 2^{-(n-1)})$.

Comment: @AnthonyQuas Hello, like I said before, the ansatz that $a_n = \mathrm{e}^{-\mu2^{-n}}$ satisfies $a^2_{n+1} = a_n$ and it satisfies the condition (ii) as well because of the asymptotic $\mathrm{e}^{-x} \approx 1 - x$ for $0 < x \ll 1$.

Comment: Fei: You have written three different versions of your condition (ii) in the question and the comments. The condition $a_n(t)\to 1-\mu 2^{-n}$ can never be satisfied. The version in your original question does not seem to be clearly formulated. If you don't have a clear question, we will not be able to answer it.

Comment: @AnthonyQuas Hello professor, the symbol $\approx$ in my original post is not interpreted rigorously like you said that $a_n - (1-\mathrm{e}^{-\mu2^{-n}}) \to 0$ is nothing different from $a_n - 1 \to 0$. I think the condition that $a_n(t) \in [0,1)$ is sufficient for my question to be "well-posed". Also, if you take $a_n = \mathrm{e}^{-\mu2^{-n}}$ then clearly it behaves like $1-\mu2^{-n}$ when $n \gg 1$.

Comment: The bottom line is that this system has a one parameter family of obvious equilibria, namely for each $\mu>0$, $a_n(t)=\exp(-\mu 2^{-n})$ is an equilibrium point for the system. I think the question should be "Under which conditions on the sequence $(a_n(0))$ belonging to $(0,1)^{\mathbb N}$ does the system converge to one of the equilibrium points? Is it for all initial conditions? Or only some initial conditions? Given an initial condition, is there a way to decide which fixed point (if any) the orbit converges to?"

Comment: @FeiCao:  Contingent on the uniqueness of solutions to this infinite-dimensional ODE, you can show that: i)[Monotonicity] $a_n(0)\leq \overline{a}_n(0)\Rightarrow a_n(t)\leq \overline{a}_n(t)$ for all $n$ and $t\geq 0$; ii) [invariance of the diagonal] $a_n(0)=a_m(0)\Rightarrow a_n(t)=a_m(t)$ for all $n,t$; iii) [dynamics on the diagonal] $a_n(0)=b\in[0,1]$ for all $n$ implies $a'_n(t)=a_n(t)^2-a_n(t)$; iv) Combining i) and iv), we have that for any sequence $(a_n(0))_{n\in\mathbb{N}}$ fulfilling  $\sup_{n\in\mathbb{N}}a_n(0)<1$, then $a_n(t)\longrightarrow 0$ for all $n$.

Comment: On the other hand, if $a_n(0)=1$ for all $n>N$ for some $N\in\mathbb{N}$, then we can easily prove that $a_n(t)\longrightarrow 1$ as $t\rightarrow \infty$ for all $n$. To grant convergence to the equilibrium that you are asking, you can neither have initial conditions bounded away from 1, i.e., $\sup_n a_n(0)<1$, nor those whose tail touches 1, i.e., $a_n(0)=1$ eventually. Which is an interesting problem.

Comment: @AugustoSantos Hello, yes I agree, the choices of initial datum matter. The assumption that $a_n(t) < 1$ for all fixed $n$ does not prevent the situation where $\sup_{n \in \mathbb N} a_n(t) = 1$ or $\sup_{n \in \mathbb N} a_n(0) = 1$

Comment: @AnthonyQuas Dear Professor, I totally agree with your comment, I was not careful enough in the statement of the initial condition

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Theorem 2 below offers a sufficient condition for convergence to the nontrivial equilibrium that you are referring.

The results are contingent on the uniqueness of solutions to this infinite-dimensional ODE -- I will include the proofs when possible, as needed, but, and unless I am missing something, they are quite simple.

**Question.** Let $\left(a_n(t)\right)_{n\in\mathbb{N}}$ be the solution to the infinite-dimensional ODE
$$a_n'(t)=a_{n+1}^2(t)-a_n(t) \,\,\,\,(\star)$$
for $n\in\mathbb{N}$, with initial condition $\left(a_n(0)\right)_{n\in\mathbb{N}}$. For which initial conditions, the solution $\left(a_n(t)\right)_{n\in\mathbb{N}}$ converges to an equilibrium distinct from the origin and the all 1's equilibrium?

**Remark 1 [Domain]**. The cube $\left[0,1\right]^{\mathbb{N}}$ is invariant to this dynamics. That is, if we initialize the system within this infinite-dimensional cube, then the solutions will remain there. You cannot impose condition i) as in your question. But, if you assume $a_n(0)\in\left[0,1\right]$ for all $n$, then $a_n(t)\in\left[0,1\right]$ for all $n,t$.

**Remark 2 [Equilibria parametrization].** The equilibria is given by $\mathcal{E}=\left\{\left(a_{n}\right)_{n\in\mathbb{N}}\,:\,a_{n+1}^2=a_n\mbox{ for all }n\right\}$ which can be rewritten as $\mathcal{E}=\left\{\left(b^{2^{-(n-1)}}\right)_{n\in\mathbb{N}}\,:\,\mbox{ for all }b\in\left[0,1\right]\right\}$. Using your parametrization, we can further write it as $\mathcal{E}=\left\{\left(e^{-\mu 2^{-(n-1)}}\right)_{n\in\mathbb{N}}\,:\,\mbox{ for all }\mu\geq0\right\}\cup \left\{\mathbf{0}\right\}$. In other words, given any $\mu\geq 0$, then the sequence $\left(e^{-\mu 2^{-(n-1)}}\right)_{n\in\mathbb{N}}$ is an equilibrium for $(\star)$. That is, this provides a one-dimensional parametrization for the equilibria of the system. In particular, let us define for simplicity
$${\sf eq}_{\mu}\overset{\Delta}=\left(e^{-\mu 2^{-(n-1)}}\right)_{n\in\mathbb{N}}$$
the equilibrium associated with the parameter $\mu\geq 0$.

**Remark 3 [Causal structure].** Observe that the evolution of $\left(a_m(t)\right)_{t\geq 0}$, for $m\geq N$, does not depend on the evolution of $\left(a_n(t)\right)_{t\geq 0}$ for any $n<N$. The state variable $a_{n+1}$ impacts $a_n$ but not the other way around. This implies the following: the *tail* of the initial condition is what determines the asymptotic behavior of this dynamical system. In other words, for any $N$, the sub-sequence of the initial condition $\left(a_n(0)\right)_{n\leq N}$ is irrelevant for the asymptotic behavior of the system.

The next result reveals an important property of this ODE.

**Lemma 1[Monotonicity].** If $a_n(0)\leq \overline{a}_n(0)$ for all $n\in\mathbb{N}$, then $a_n(t)\leq \overline{a}_n(t)$ for all $n\in\mathbb{N}$ and $t\geq 0$.

We have an immediate corollary to Lemma 1.

**Corollary 1 [Invariant sub-regions].** Let $\mu_1<\mu_2$. If there exists $N\in\mathbb{N}$ so that $e^{-\mu_2 2^{-(n-1)}}\leq a_{n}(0)\leq e^{-\mu_1 2^{-(n-1)}}$ for all $n\geq N$, then $e^{-\mu_2 2^{-(n-1)}}\leq \lim\inf_{t\rightarrow \infty}a_{n}(t)\leq \lim\sup_{t\rightarrow \infty}a_{n}(t)\leq e^{-\mu_1 2^{-(n-1)}}$ for all $n\in\mathbb{N}$.

As a consequence to Corollary 1, if the initial condition $\left(a_n(0)\right)_{n\in\mathbb{N}}$ is bounded as $e^{-\mu_2 2^{-(n-1)}}\leq a_{n}(0)\leq e^{-\mu_1 2^{-(n-1)}}$ eventually, i.e., for $n\geq N$ for some $N$, then the dynamical system $\left(a_n(t)\right)_{n\in\mathbb{N}}$ cannot converge to ${\sf eq}_{\mu}$ for any $\mu\notin \left[\mu_1,\mu_2\right]$.

**Theorem 1 [Monotonicity 2].** If $a_n(0)<a_{n+1}(0)^2$ for all $n$, then $a_n(t)$ is increasing in $t$ for all $n$, i.e., $a_{n}(t)>a_{n}(t')$ for any $t>t'$ and for any $n$.

As a corollary to Theorem 1, and to the fact that $a_n(t)\in\left[0,1\right]$ for all $t$, we have convergence to an equilibrium whenever the initial condition is given by $a_n(0)<a_{n+1}(0)^2$ for all $n$. In particular, via combining Corollary 1 and Theorem 1, we have the following sufficient condition for convergence to a nontrivial equilibrium.

**Theorem 2 [Sufficient condition].** If $a_n(0)<a_{n+1}(0)^2$ for all $n$, and further $e^{-\mu_2 2^{-(n-1)}}<a_n(0)<e^{-\mu_1 2^{-(n-1)}}$ eventually for some $\mu_1,\mu_2\in\left(0,\infty\right)$, then there exists $\mu\in\left[\mu_1,\mu_2\right]$ so that $a_n(t)\overset{t\rightarrow \infty}\longrightarrow e^{-\mu2^{-(n-1)}}$ for all $n$.

--------------------------- **Other results** --------------------------------------

**Lemma 2[Invariance of the diagonal].** If $a_n(0)=b\in \left[0,1\right]$ for all $n$, then $a_n(t)=a_m(t)$ for all $n,m$. In particular, $a_n'(t)=a_n(t)^2-a_n(t)$ for all $n$.

The proof is trivial, but relies on the uniqueness of solutions to the ODE $(\star)$.

**Theorem 3 [Origin's attraction].** If $\sup_{n\in\mathbb{N}} a_n(0)<1$, then, $a_n(t)\overset{t\rightarrow \infty}\longrightarrow 0$ for all $n\in\mathbb{N}$.

> *Proof.* Consider the sequence $\left(\overline{a}_n(0)\right)_n$ so that $\overline{a}_n(0)=\sup_{n\in\mathbb{N}}a_n(0)=:c\in\left(0,1\right)$ for all $n$. Then, from Lemma 1, we have that $\overline{a}_n(t)\geq a_n(t)$ for all $n$ and $t\geq 0$. From Lemma 2, we have that $\overline{a}'_n(t)=\overline{a}_n(t)^2-\overline{a}_n(t)$. Therefore, $\overline{a}_n(t)\overset{t\rightarrow \infty}\longrightarrow 0$ for all $n$. Thus, $a_n(t)\overset{t\rightarrow \infty}\longrightarrow 0$ from the boundedness and since $\left[0,1\right]^{\mathbb{N}}$ is invariant to the infinite-dimensional dynamical system $(\star)$.

**Theorem 4 [1's attraction].** If $a_n(0)=1$, for all $n>N$ for some $N\in\mathbb{N}$ large enough, then $a_n(t)\overset{t\rightarrow \infty}\longrightarrow 1$ for all $n\in\mathbb{N}$.

> *Proof.* It is trivial to check that $a_n(t)=1$ for all $t\geq 0$ for all $n>N$. we have $a_n'(t)=1-a_n(t)$ for $n=N$ and hence $a_n(t)\overset{t\rightarrow \infty}\longrightarrow 1$. From here, it is trivial to check that $a_n(t)\longrightarrow 1$ for all $n$.

Comment: Nice! I haven’t yet written anything down, but I suspect that one can construct solutions that don’t converge to any equilibrium: let $\mu\ne \mu’$ and set $b_n=\exp(2^{-n}\mu)$ and $b_n’=\exp(2^{-n}\mu’)$. Then if $a_n(0)$ is set to be $b_n$ for a long block; then $b_n’$ for an even longer block; and then $b_n$ for a still longer block etc. then it seems as though (all finite portions of) the system would oscillate between behaving like the $\mu$ equilibrium and line the $\mu’$ equilibrium. I don’t think this is incompatible with anything you’ve written?

Comment: Another comment: your answer shows, I think that if $2^n\log a_n(0)\to\mu$ then the system converges to the $\mu$ equilibrium. This is along the lines of the OP’s question.

Comment: Thank you for your wonderful answer! I have added more contexts in my OP (yes, the requirements on the initial datum can be assumed to be true as well). By the way, may I cite this answer (as I might want to use a simplified version of this in a short Appendix of a paper) ?

Comment: @AnthonyQuas: Thank you. Incidently, while thinking about the stability of the equilibria, I was also thinking about possibilities of no-convergence to equilibrium (e.g., oscillatory behavior and chaoticity). I don't think we would need to go as far as resorting to this "bigger-blocks" initial conditions example -- It is already not clear to me, whether a simple oscillatory tail would not compromise convergence to equilibrium. The extra condition "$a_{n}(0)<a_{n+1}(0)^2$" prevents the oscilatory behavior (if everything is in place) yielding a well enough behaved tail (in view of Theorem 1).

Comment: @FeiCao: Thank you. Of course, please, feel free to use whatever needed in your paper if it helps.

Comment: @AugustoSantos: somehow I suspect that simple oscillation between $\mu$ and $\mu’$ may not be sufficient to avoid convergence to an equilibrium, but I have done no calculation whatsoever. On the other hand, I think easy soft arguments should work for block behavior.

Comment: @AnthonyQuas: Indeed, to avoid convergence to equilibria, I start believing that we need to initialize the system with something along your block example (with blocks scaling up to infinite). For example, let $\mu_1>\mu_2$. If we initialize with $a_n(0)= e^{-\mu_1 2^{-(n-1)}}$ if $n$ is odd, and $a_n(0)= e^{-\mu_2 2^{-(n-1)}}$ for $n$ even, then (I believe, but not sure) we have $a^2_{n+1}(t)>a_n(t)$ for all $t$ when $n$ is odd and $a^2_{n+1}(t)<a_n(t)$ for all $t$ when $n$ is even. Which would still grant convergence to ${\sf eq}_\mu$ for some $\mu_2<\mu<\mu_1$.

Comment: Via monotonicity (in a version that extends Lemma 1), we would have convergence to some ${\sf eq}_{\mu}$ for any initial condition given by: $a_n(0)>e^{-\mu_1 2^{-(n-1)}}$ for any $n$ odd and  $a_n(0)<e^{-\mu_2 2^{-(n-1)}}$ for any $n$ even. Solutions of initial conditions bounded this way would be squized to the equilibrium ${\sf eq}_{\mu}$ by the solution initialized as in my previous comment. This would extend Theorem 2. However, for initial conditions with the block format, it seems quite clear that the system cannot pick one equilibrium to converge to (unless uniqueness does not hold).